# I can't edit a Text object in Blender

Tags: text-editor

[image: I'm in the latest version of blender`]

I have both tabbed into edit mode (with nothing else selected) and used the dropdown menu.

why won't it let me edit the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've converted your text to a mesh, it is not editable any more. The solution is to recreate a text, edit it if it's necessary, and only convert to mesh when you're finished with it.